# Is there a single Poisson constant for mixtures of gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

Let's say air consists of 79% nitrogen and 21% diatomic gas. To perform calculations on $\Delta H$ on adiabatic expansions, instead of taking them as individual parts, can I take the air to be a uniform gas with some [Poisson constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) $\gamma = C_p/C_v$, and if I do that, what would $\gamma$ will be?

Comment: Poisson's ratio for a gas? Is that defined? I thought it applied only to elastic solids. Most gases are close to ideal unless the density gets very high, so a mixture will also behave as an ideal gas.

Comment: poisson's ratio of gases: γ=Cp/Cv

Comment: @JohnRennie the [_isentropic bulk modulus of a gas_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus#Thermodynamic_relation) is defined as $\gamma p$.

Answer (score 2):

Nitrogen is a diatomic gas as well... so the $\gamma$ of air is very close to the $\gamma$ or either oxygen or nitrogen - $$\gamma=\frac75$$

So yes - you should be able to treat air as uniform for your calculation.